# JQuery Validation Plug In is forcing a double click to submit the form

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-plugins, validation

I have to click the submit button twice on my form in order to submit it. How do I make it so the user only has to click submit? However, I do not want onfocusout nor onkeyup enabled. I just want my form to be validated through clicking the submit button only.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.validator.setDefaults({
          onfocusout: false,
          onkeyup: false
        });

        $.validator.addMethod("username", function(value, element) {
           return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z]+$/i.test(value);
            }, "Your username may only contain letters");

        var validator = $("#registerForm").validate({
          showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
            $("#registerForm").find("input").each(function() {
                $(this).removeClass("error");
            });
            $("#errorcontainer").html("");
            if(errorList.length) {
              $("#errorcontainer").html(errorList[0]['message']);
              $(errorList[0]['element']).addClass("error");
              $('#errorcontainer').css('display','none');
              $('#errorcontainer').fadeIn(400);
            }
            else {
              $('#errorcontainer').css('display','none');
            }
          },

          rules: {
            username: {
              required: true,
              rangelength: [3,15],
              remote: "usernamevalidation.php"
            },
            password: {
              required: true,
              rangelength: [5,20]
            },
            passwordconfirm: {
              required: true,
              equalTo: "#password"
            },
            email: {
              required: true,
              email: true,
              remote: "emailvalidation.php"
            }
          },

          messages: {
            username: {
              required: "You must enter a username.",
              rangelength: "Your username must be between {0} and {1} letters.",
              remote: "Your desired username is already in use."
            },
            password: {
              required: "You must enter a password.",
              rangelength: "Your password must be between {0} and {1} letters."
            },
            passwordconfirm: {
              required: "Your passwords must match.",
              equalTo: "Your passwords must match."
            },
            email: {
              required: "You must enter an email address.",
              email: "Your email address is not valid.",
              remote: "This email is already in use."
            }
          }
        });
      });
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `onsubmit: true` to the defaults?

Comment: I just did and it did not work unfortunately :/

Comment: If you want help you should help us help you.  Link the source for the plugin and even more importantly, link to an example so we can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I used the shubmitHandler that comes with jquery validate

`submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
    return false
});`

I Hope it helps you

Comment: What's the logic behind that?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what fixed this for me:

- Use jQuery 1.5.2
- Use jQuery Validate v 1.8.0

  - https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js
- http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.min.js

FYI, I'm also using jQuery UI (v1.8.11) with no issues regarding the above:

- https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and resolved it by adding the following to my validate:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  onfocusout: false
});
```

See more at https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Answer (score 0):

Use remote like that

```
remote:{
url: "emailvalidation.php",
async:false
}
```

Here "async:false" is allow to submit form on first click,
Hope it help u.